# docker image leads to containers with different tensorflow versions

Tags: docker, tensorflow, kubernetes

I have a Dockerfile in which I create a python environment using miniconda. This environment implicity installs a tensorflow version through specifying a rasa_core version 0.11.11. So I build an image from this Dockerfile. Now if I create a container locally with docker, I find the tensorflow version to be 1.10. However if I use the image in an deployment on kubernetes, the container crashes and the logs show that code from tensorflow version 1.11 is the cause. How is this possible?

Comment: this is impossible. Just because under the hood this images will be run by the same `docker` . The only thing might happened is a pulling (imagePullPolicy: Always) before container starts. You need to compare images sha256 hashes via `docker images --digests`.

Comment: The hashes of the created container in the deployment indeed turned out to be different from the stored image in the container registry. Seemed to be a garbage collection problem of kubernetes. Creating a new cluster solved it.